# How to get paypal partner name and vandor name for credit card from paypal pro setup in magneto 2

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I am trying set up PayPal Payments Pro in Magento 2 with sandbox credentials. It needs partner, user, vendor, password.

Can anyone tell me where to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Payflow uses its own test mode to process simulated transactions

Whether it also connects to the PayPal sandbox or not, depends on whether you have a Payflow account with PayPal as the processor

Here is a guide with the information you need: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/test-hosted-pages/#create-a-test-only-payflow-gateway-account